# Unmerge a Merged Room

Tags: fallout-shelter

Can a merged room be unmerged without destroying it first?

It's related to my personal aesthetical preference, if you ever ask me why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Once the room is merged, it's considered one room. You have to destroy the whole thing to remove one of them.